# sql select to get older than 15 days with multiple where clause

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

I`m trying to get information out of a database that is more than 15 days old and is in a status used and category nature but for some reason the results seem to come close to what I was expecting but not right. It seems to be a few days out and if there are none that are applicable it still shows 8 results.

Anybody know where I might be going wrong?

The code I have is:

```
SELECT * FROM Galleries
WHERE Status = 'Used' AND Category = 'Nature' 
AND Display_Date >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAY(curdate())+6 DAY
ORDER BY Display_Date LIMIT 8
```

Answer (score 1):

Your are getting 8 result each time because of your `LIMIT 8`, you also are selecting records from today + 6 days, better to use `INTERVAL 15 DAY`. I think you should also use `<=` instead of `=>` since you stated you are looking for records which are odler than 15 days

```
SELECT * FROM Galleries
WHERE Status = 'Used' AND Category = 'Nature' 
AND Display_Date <= curdate() - INTERVAL 15 DAY
ORDER BY Display_Date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AND Display_Date >= (curdate() - INTERVAL 15 DAY)
```

would probably be better. If you want 15 days, then that `+6 DAY` isn't going to help much.